# How to define breaks of the bins for log scale in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram

Consider the following minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Area":[0.5, 0.05, 0.005]
})

sns.histplot(
    data=df,
    x="Area",
    bins=3,
    log_scale=True
)
```

The minimal working example above will produce

[image: Seaborn histogram with log scale]

Now, let's use our own breaks of the bins:

```
sns.histplot(
    data=df,
    x="Area",
    bins=np.logspace(-3, 0, num=4),
    log_scale=True
)
```

I expected to produce a histogram similar to the one before but I'm getting

[image]

What am I doing wrongly? Or is this a bug with Seaborn 0.11.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you have to give the bins on the log scale. I.e. with `bins=np.logspace(-3, 0, 4)` you're getting bins at `10**np.logspace(-3, 0, 4)`. Use `linspace` instead and you should be getting what you're looking for. `bins=np.linspace(-3, 0, 4)` gives breaks at `10**np.linspace(-3, 0, 4)`:

```
sns.histplot(
    data=df,
    x="Area",
    bins=np.linspace(-3, 0, num=4),
    log_scale=True
)
```